# How to detect if test is running on GitLab CI server

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a test, which is using MySQL database configured and running on gitlab CI server (gitlab-ci.yml). I want that test to be disabled when it's running locally (it's using in-memory database instead). Is there any way to check if the test is running on GitLab Ci server? Something like:

```
if(isRunningOnGitlabCi()) {
  Assert.assertThat(...);
}
```

Maybe there's environmental variable, which I can check ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Gitlab CI [defines a large number of environment variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html); you could use e.g. `GITLAB_CI`.

Something like:

```java
if(System.getenv("GITLAB_CI") != null) {
  Assert.assertThat(...);
}
```

Comment: Just to point out that this is valid for python, it helped me a lot, thanks!